# Nested parent/child checkboxes - working solution need adjustment help for Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, parent-child

I have been looking for a 'complete' solution to nesting parent child checkboxes that change state correctly based on a hierarchy.

Most 'solutions' do not work or only work to one level. They also require you to name the checkboxes in a particular way.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339389/auto-check-parent-checkbox)  Stack Overflow discussion covers the main points but also provide a good solution discovered by Rory [here](http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/).

I have tested it within my development project and it works perfectly standalone. However, I am using Bootstrap 2.x and for checkboxes

I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mvs87/1/) which shows the working example code, then my version with a disabled parent checkbox and then the bootsrap code version which does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<!-- Raw working example from site http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/ -->

<b>Raw working example</b>
<p>
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tall" id="tall">
        <label for="tall">Tall Things</label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tall-1" id="tall-1">
                <label for="tall-1">Buildings</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tall-2" id="tall-2">
                <label for="tall-2">Giants</label>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="tall-2-1" id="tall-2-1">
                        <label for="tall-2-1">Andre</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="tall-2-2" id="tall-2-2">
                        <label for="tall-2-2">Paul Bunyan</label>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="tall-2-2-1" id="tall-2-2-1">
                                <label for="tall-2-2-1">Son</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="tall-2-2-2" id="tall-2-2-2">
                                <label for="tall-2-2-2">Daughter</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tall-3" id="tall-3">
                <label for="tall-3">Two sandwiches</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="short" id="short">
        <label for="short">Short Things</label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="short-1" id="short-1">
                <label for="short-1">Smurfs</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="short-2" id="short-2">
                <label for="short-2">Mushrooms</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="short-3" id="short-3">
                <label for="short-3">One Sandwich</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<hr>

<!-- Non Bootstrap Example -->
<b>My initial code example - Is Working</b>
<p>
<ul>
    <li>

        <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" disabled><strong>Ford</strong>

        <ul>
            <li>

                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Fiesta</label>
            </li>
            <li>

                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Focus</label>
            </li>
            <li>

                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Mondeo</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>

        <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" disabled><strong>Vauxhall</strong>


        <ul>
            <li>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Corsa</label>
            </li>
            <li>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Astra</label>
            </li>
            <li>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Vectra</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

            <hr>

<!-- Bootstrap Example -->

<b>Bootstrap based code example - Not Working</b>
<p>

<ul>
    <li>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" disabled><strong>Ford</strong>

        </label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Fiesta</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Focus</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Mondeo</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" disabled><strong>Vauxhall</strong>

        </label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Corsa</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Astra</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Vectra</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```javascript
$(function () {
  // Apparently click is better chan change? Cuz IE?
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function (e) {
      var checked = $(this).prop("checked"),
          container = $(this).parent(),
          siblings = container.siblings();

      container.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
          indeterminate: false,
          checked: checked
      });

      function checkSiblings(el) {
          var parent = el.parent().parent(),
              all = true;

          el.siblings().each(function () {
              return all = ($(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") === checked);
          });

          if (all && checked) {
              parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                  indeterminate: false,
                  checked: checked
              });
              checkSiblings(parent);
          } else if (all && !checked) {
              parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", checked);
              parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("indeterminate", (parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0));
              checkSiblings(parent);
          } else {
              el.parents("li").children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                  indeterminate: true,
                  checked: false
              }); 
          } 
      } 

      checkSiblings(container); 
  }); 
});
```

My understanding is that the code needs to be changed somewhere to use **parents** or **closest**. Can someone who is a much better code please help identify where the change needs to happen to get the Bootstrap version working.

Comment: Have you tried to use one of the available treeview components (around the JQuery framework)? They usually provide this kind of functionality. If you're interested please let me know (by replying to this comment).

Comment: Matt, Would be interested in any extra information that you have using a treeview component. Thanks

Comment: I've posted an answer, please look into the link provided there and let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the free [JSTree](http://www.jstree.com/) user control. It is JavaScript-based, open source and allows to be configured for multiple styles of tree views, for example:

[image]

Since the checkboxes displayed here are just images, you can replace them by radio buttons easily, and via event handling you can disallow multiple selections so they behave like radio buttons if required.

This is achieved by specifying the `"checkbox"` plugin as follows (see the snippet I provided below for the complete working code):

```
$(function () {
    $("#demo1")
        .jstree({
        "themes": {
            "theme": "apple","dots": false,"icons": false
        },
        "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "checkbox", "sort", "ui"]
    });
});
```

The corresponding HTML structure looks like this, just include it in the body of your page:

```
<div id="demo1" class="demo" style="height:100px;">
    <ul>
        <li id="phtml_1">   <a href="#">Root node 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="phtml_2">   <a href="#">Child node 1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="phtml_3">   <a href="#">Child node 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="phtml_4">   <a href="#">Root node 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

To get the checked values, use this function (assuming you have created a div with `id="listForDisplay"` as I did in the JSFiddle example):

```
var $listForDisplay = $("#listForDisplay");
function displayList(data) { // see: https://www.jstree.com/docs/events/
    var i, j, r = [];
    for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
        r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);
    }
    $listForDisplay.html('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
}
```

This code can either be triggered in a click event or you can bind JSTree events like I did. Appending the following to the previous JavaScript snippet does the job:

```
    $("#demo1")
    .on('loaded.jstree', function (e, data) {
            displayList(data);
        })
    .on('change_state.jstree', function (e, data) {
            displayList(data);
        });
```

**Note:** When a parent node is selected, the parent name is listed along with the childs. If only the childs are selected, the related parent(s) will not be listed.

You can find more about the options specifying the behaviour of this plugin [here](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/checkbox).

---

**Runnable code snippet (complete code)**

```js
$(function() {

  var $demo1 = $("#demo1");
  
  var $listForDisplay = $("#listForDisplay");
  function displayList(data) { // see: https://www.jstree.com/docs/events/
    var i, j, r = [];
    for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
      r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);
    }
    $listForDisplay.html('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
  }

  $demo1.jstree({
    "themes": {
      "theme": "apple",
      "dots": false,
      "icons": false
    },
    "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "checkbox", "sort", "ui"]
  });
  $demo1.on('loaded.jstree', function(e, data) {
    displayList(data);
  });
  $demo1.on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {
    displayList(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="demo1" class="demo" style="height:100px;">
    <ul>
      <li id="phtml_1"> <a href="#">Root node 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li id="phtml_2"> <a href="#">Child node 1</a>
          </li>
          <li id="phtml_3"> <a href="#">Child node 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="phtml_4"> <a href="#">Root node 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div id="listForDisplay" />
</body>
```

Comment: True, and it might happen the unwanted tag reappears because it was not noticed it got rejected. Might be something for MetaSO.

Comment: undesirable tags that keep cropping up are eventually blacklisted (**the tags that is**; not that that's anything bad against their authors)

Comment: @Richard: Let's remove our comments from here, I believe they belonged to a discussion not relevant for this answer.

Answer (score 4):

you can try something like this

```
  $(function () {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function (e) {
      var checked = $(this).prop("checked"),
          container = $(this).closest("li"),//get closest li instead of parent
          siblings = container.siblings();
      container.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
          indeterminate: false,
          checked: checked
      });

      function checkSiblings(el) {
          var parent = el.parent().parent(),
              all = true,
              parentcheck=parent.children("label");//get the label that contains the disabled checkbox
          el.siblings().each(function () {
              return all = ($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") === checked);
          });
          //use parentcheck instead of parent to get the children checkbox
          if (all && checked) {
              parentcheck.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                  indeterminate: false,
                  checked: checked
              });
              checkSiblings(parent);
          } else if (all && !checked) {
              parentcheck.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", checked);
              parentcheck.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("indeterminate", (parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0));
              checkSiblings(parent);
          } else {
             parentcheck.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                  indeterminate: true,
                  checked: false
              });
          }
      }
      checkSiblings(container);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mvs87/2/