# Display nested checkbox form from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, forms, spring-mvc, jsp

I am using Spring MVC to create a web application, and using jsp to create the views. I have a nested JSON object where I don't know how many levels there are of the form:

```
{
    "outer" : "group1",  
    "inner" : [
        {
            "outer" : "group2", 
            "inner":[
                {
                    "outer" : "group3", 
                    "inner": ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "outer" : "group4", 
            "inner": ["item4"]
        }
    ]            
}
```

I want to create a nested checkbox form that looks like this:

```
❑ group1
    ❑ group2
        ❑ group3
            ❑ item1
            ❑ item2
            ❑ item3
    ❑ group4
        ❑ item4
```

Where checking the box next to one of the outer level groups will check the box of all of its children. I am new to Spring and jsp, and I can't seem to find a simple, straightforward way to achieve this. What is the cleanest way to implement something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested parent/child checkboxes - working solution need adjustment help for Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355375/nested-parent-child-checkboxes-working-solution-need-adjustment-help-for-boots)